# How empty cells in tikz table (matrix)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, arrays, tikz-matrix

I am trying to recreate below table in tikz (I need because I could use tikz in my jupyter notebook to render *embedded* output but not yet latex)

[image]

When I try via tikz I only get this far..

[image]

**My MWE:**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}

\matrix[square matrix]
{
1 & &  & & & & \\ 
2 & x & & & & & \\ 
3 & x & x & & & & \\ 
4 & x & x & x & & & \\ 
5 & x & x & x & x & & \\ 
6 & x & x & x & x & x & \\ 
};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sebastiano provided the solution for missing cells and how to fill each one, but it's also possible to define `styles` for complet rows and columns. And with some extra works draw the top left cell.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{%
square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum size=#1,
      anchor=center,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    column 1/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!30}},
    row 1/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!30}},
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}

\matrix[square matrix] (A)
{
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 
1 & & & & & & \\ 
2 & x & & & & & \\ 
3 & x & x & & & &   \\ 
4 & x & x & x & & & \\ 
5 & x & x & x & x & & \\ 
6 & x & x & x & x & x & \\ 
};

\draw (A-1-1.north west)--(A-1-1.south east);
\node[below left=2mm and 2mm of A-1-1.north east] {$i$};
\node[above right=2mm and 2mm of A-1-1.south west] {$j$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**:

To obtain some special color distribution like in your [link](https://i.postimg.cc/J7qdpCWp/image.png)

[image]

you can mix some automating filling for regular rows and columns and some manual filling on background:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, backgrounds}

\tikzset{%
square matrix/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum width=#1,
      minimum height=.5*#1,
      anchor=center,
%      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    row 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [square matrix]
{
j\backslash i  & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6\\    
y_1 & R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} & R_{14} & R_{15} & R_{16} \\ 
y_2 & R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} & R_{24} & R_{25} & R_{26} \\ 
y_3 & R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33} & R_{34} & R_{35} & R_{36} \\ 
y_4 & R_{41} & R_{42} & R_{43} & R_{44} & R_{45} & R_{46} \\ 
y_5 & R_{51} & R_{52} & R_{53} & R_{54} & R_{55} & R_{56} \\ 
y_6 & R_{61} & R_{62} & R_{63} & R_{64} & R_{65} & R_{66} \\ 
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[cyan!15] (A-3-2.north west)-|(A-4-3.north west)-|(A-5-4.north west)-|(A-6-5.north west)-|(A-7-6.north west)-|(A-7-6.south east)-|cycle;
\fill[red!15] (A-2-3.north west)|-(A-3-4.north west)
|-(A-4-5.north west)|-(A-5-6.north west)|-(A-6-7.north west)|-(A-6-7.south east)
|-cycle;
\foreach \i in {2,...,7}
    \fill[gray!30] (A-\i-\i.north west) rectangle (A-\i-\i.south east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd Update**:

You could construct an automatic solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, backgrounds}

\tikzset{%
myfill/.code={%
    \ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<\pgfmatrixcurrentrow
        \pgfkeysalso{fill=cyan!30}
    \else
        \ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>\pgfmatrixcurrentrow
            \pgfkeysalso{fill=red!30}
        \else
            \pgfkeysalso{fill=gray!20}
        \fi
    \fi
    },
square matrix/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,
        myfill,
      minimum width=#1,
      minimum height=.5*#1,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt,
      node contents={
        R_{\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1\relax%
        \the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1\relax%
      }}
    },
    column 1/.style={
        nodes={fill=gray!30,
        node contents={y_\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1\relax}
        }},
    row 1/.style={
        nodes={fill=gray!30,
        node contents={x_\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1\relax}
        }},
     row 1 column 1/.style={
        nodes={fill=gray!30,
        node contents={j\backslash i}
        }},
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [square matrix]
{
&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvoted quickly you. Excellent.

Comment: great, can you also please explain what is happening? how are the colors filled for entire row and column?

Comment: @PaariVendhan with declarations `row 1/.style` and `column 1/.style`.

Comment: @Ignasi Please, could you help the OP to create a macro for the image that have put into my comments?

Comment: @Ignasi ```column 1/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!30}},``` means, every 1st cell of all columns?

Comment: @PaariVendhan No. It means every cell im first column.

Comment: @paarivendhan I've made a second update with a more automatic version for writting and coloring matrices like this one.

Answer (score 6):

I have added to the your LaTeX code the option:

```
\matrix[square matrix, nodes in empty cells]
{
&   &   &   &\\
```

Surely adding or deleting `&` you can create (not create) others empty cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}

\matrix[square matrix, nodes in empty cells]
{
&   &   &   &\\
1 & &  & & & & \\ 
2 & x & & & & & \\ 
3 & x & x & & & & \\ 
4 & x & x & x & & & \\ 
5 & x & x & x & x & & \\ 
6 & x & x & x & x & x & \\ 
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:**

I have fill one only cell. With the same structure you can fill one or more cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}

\matrix[square matrix, nodes in empty cells]
{
|[fill=green]|&   &   &   &\\
1 & &  & & & & \\ 
2 & x & & & & & \\ 
3 & x & x & & & & \\ 
4 & x & x & x & & & \\ 
5 & x & x & x & x & & \\ 
6 & x & x & x & x & x & \\ 
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ```nodes in empty cells``` fixed the issue. However is it possible to recreate as my table 1 as shown? esp, that diagonally cut top left cell?

Comment: Do you prefer fill the cells?

Comment: filling the cell with color? yes

Comment: Done! I have added the your request.

Comment: great, can you please show how do I make a macro out of this, as I have special needs to color the cells.. something like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/J7qdpCWp/image.png)

Comment: With a lot of patience you can create your image with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{000000} $R_{11}$} &  &  &  &  \\
                                                        &  &  &  &  \\
                                                        &  &  &  &  \\
                                                        &  &  &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}` using this [link](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85132/discussion-between-paari-vendhan-and-sebastiano).