# Double entry table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I would like to make a double entry table in LaTeX.

Here is the result that I would like to get:

[image]

I found a clue [here](https://bluenalgene.github.io/LaTeX_Guided_Course/04-tables/index.html):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ c || l | r | c }
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Columns} \\ \hline \hline
      \multirow{3}{*}{Rows}
      & A1 & B1 & C1 \\ \cline{2-4}
      & A222 & B22 & C2 \\ \cline{2-4}
      & A3 & B333 & C33
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I managed to get a partial solution:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ l || r | c }
          A1 & B1 & C1 \\ \hline \hline
          A222 & B22 & C2 \\ \hline
          A3 & B333 & C33
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, it doesn't solve all my problems. Is it possible to get square cells with everything centered in the cell? I found other partial solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457679/how-empty-cells-in-tikz-table-matrix) but I don't know tikz at all. The matrix environment might not suit my needs because I would like to avoid outer borders and I didn't find any solution with double lines separing row's titles from the inner cells.

Comment: Did you google for e.g.  latex diagonal line in table which gives according to me already a potential result: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's something you could manage with François Pantigny's `nicematrix` package. I'm not that an expert of it to provide a complete working solution, but it will pop one of these days.

Answer (score 2):

I use plain TikZ. You can fine turn everything as desired. In particular, `double distance` to adjust distance inside the double lines.

About scaling, I propose 2 manner. The first one is scaling the whole picture with `[scale=.8]`; the text will not be affected.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\draw (0,0)--(1,-1) (0,-2)--(3,-2) (2,0)--(2,-3);
\draw[double,double distance=.5pt] (0,-1)--(3,-1) (1,0)--(1,-3) ;
\path[magenta]
(1.5,-.5) node{2} ++(0:1) node{3}
(.5,-1.5) node{4} ++(0:1) node{8}  +(0:1) node{12}
(.5,-2.5) node{5} ++(0:1) node{10} +(0:1) node{15}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The 2nd way is scaling only nodes with `nodes={scale=.6}`; the lines will not be affected.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,-1) (0,-2)--(3,-2) (2,0)--(2,-3);
\draw[double,double distance=.5pt] (0,-1)--(3,-1) (1,0)--(1,-3);
\path[teal,nodes={scale=.6}]
(1.5,-.5) node{2} ++(0:1) node{3}
(.5,-1.5) node{4} ++(0:1) node{8}  +(0:1) node{12}
(.5,-2.5) node{5} ++(0:1) node{10} +(0:1) node{15}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I get double lines between row's names and inner cells?

Comment: @Dunno `\draw[gray,double] ...` Is that what you want?

Comment: I posted the table to show what I would like. I edited the main message.

Comment: @Dunno pls my update codes and comment!

Comment: I made a mistake when I edited. I (re)edited it. What's the limit of what can be written in a cell?

Comment: @Dunno You did not actually read my code. The only change needed from my code is moving `(0,-2)--(3,-2) (2,0)--(2,-3)` to the `\draw` command. Anyway, I have just edited the code according to new edit of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, I'm not that a specialist of the `nicematrix` package, so I didn't come with a complete corresponding answer. Anyway, it's a start and sure someone (maybe François himself) would come and improve that solution.

[image: nicematrix1]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    $\begin{NiceTabular}{W{c}{1cm}|W{c}{1cm}|W{c}{1cm}}
    \diagbox{}{}& 2 & 3 \\
    \hline \hline
    4 & 8 & 12 \\
    \hline
    5 & 10 & 15
    \end{NiceTabular}$

\end{document}
```

The main problem is that you may think that by adding a vertical line in the table declaration, it would be good, but that doesn't work fine:

`$\begin{NiceTabular}{W{c}{1cm}||W{c}{1cm}|W{c}{1cm}}`

[image: nicematrix 2]